# ?:0: attempt to index field 'parent' (a nil value)

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

Full error:

```
Runtime error
?:0: attempt to index field 'parent' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ?: in function <?:565>
        ?: in function <?:221>
```

I've read multiple topics about it, none was helpful. The code works perfectly on the other computer, so there's no error in code.

I've noticed that this error is provided by ScrollView widget.If i insert any element that's been required from another .lua file and change scene-s the error will stay in loop at Simulator Output.

I have uninstalled/installed Corona multiple times, also restarted my computer several times, no changes.

Full project code was copied to other computer and it worked w/o any errors.

Is there a way to uninstall every little bit of corona? Since the project history stays after uninstall. I have also cleared appData, do i really need to format my computer to get it working again?

*Edit*

Also i have multiple projects, the older ones have the same error now..

SOLUTION:
The problem was because of the bug in daily build, reverted some older version of Corona fixed the issue

Comment: This is a code error of some sort. Showing us the code involved will help. Even if the problem is with corona.

Comment: Theres no need for code, since older code does not work also, nothing workis with scrollView

BUT!

I've found a solution, the bug is in corona version..
I was using version 2015.2646, that had this bug (the current version),
so now i installed the version the other computer had (2014.2511) and everything is working again :)

Comment: Or your code is broken and it just happened to work in the older version of corona for some reason, but sure.

Comment: What version of Corona SDK is installed on the Computer that is working?  What version is installed on the Computer that is not.

You also need to post some code around this error. There is very likely more information in your device's console log that might tell you where the problem is.  Please read: http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/debugging/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with Corona's widget library. I noticed people were finding similar errors last year here https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/49750-attempt-to-index-field-parent-a-nil-value/

I would recommend contacting some Corona devs or posting the issue on their forums.